# local extremum of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, constraints

> Let $A = \{(x_1,x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 \leq 1\}$ and $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) := x_1^2 + x_2^3 - 2x_1x_2 - x_3^2$ for $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in A.$ By the EVT and continuity of $f, f$ must attain a global maximum. Prove that all points of global maximum are on the unit sphere $S = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \sum_{i=1}^3 x_i^2 = 1\}$.

I know that points of local maximum are critical points. We have that $\nabla f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is $(2x_1 -2x_2, 3x_2^2 - 2x_1, -2x_3).$ This is zero iff $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (0,0,0)$ or $(0,\frac{2}3, \frac{2}3),$ but neither of these points are global maxima for $f$ (we easily have $f(1,0,0) = f(0,1,0) = 1$, which is greater than the value of $f$ at both of these points).  By the second derivative test, $f$ attains a local maximum at a point where the Hessian of $f$ at $\vec{a} \in A$, whose $(i,j)$ entry is $\partial_i \partial_j f(\vec{a})$, is negative semi-definite. We have that the Hessian of $f$ is given by $Hf(\vec{a}) = \begin{bmatrix}2 & -2 & 0\\
-2 & 6a_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2\end{bmatrix}\,\forall \vec{a} = (a_1, a_2, a_3).$ For a column vector $\vec{z} = (a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3, z^T Hf(\vec{a})z = (2a-2b)a + (-2a + 6a_2 b) -2c^2.$ I'm not sure how to use this to determine local maxima though.

Comment: I think what you have done in the first part is enough to prove the statement because you have proven that a value on the unit sphere is greater than any critical point

Comment: @Tortar unfortunately I don't think that argument works. There are many values of $f$ inside the sphere that are greater than the critical points. For instance, take the value at $(\frac{1}6, \frac{5}6, 0)$ or the value at $(\frac{1}4, \frac{\sqrt{3}}2, 0)$.

Comment: sorry, I don't know much of multivariable calculus yet ahah

Answer (score 1):

Let's define $\mathring{A}:=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mid x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2<1\}$ and $cl(A):=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mid x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1\}$, so $A=\mathring{A}\cup cl(A)$.

We can find all possible points $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \mathring{A}$ which might attain a global maximum by setting $Df(x_1,x_2,x_3)\overset{!}{=}0$ (first order condidtion aka F.O.C.) and then verifying that those points indeed lie in $\mathring{A}$. This is what you have already done and as you have pointed out those points are no global maxima nor do they lie on the unit sphere. As the function is continuous and defined on a compact set it must attain a **global** maximum (and a **global** minimum). We can easily find points $(x,y,z)$ and $(a,b,c)$ on $cl(A)$ which satisfy $f(x,y,z)>f(0,0,0)$ and $f(a,b,c)<f(0,\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3})$. So the **global** extrema must be attained by points in $cl(A)$. Hence, they lie on the unit sphere.

Comment: @FredJefferson, yes it is incorrect. How do you argue that $(x-y)^2<1$? Check $x=0.5$ and $y=-0.5$.

Comment: you're right. My argument really was pointless, since one could just take $(x,y,z) = (0.866, -0.5,0)$ which is an interior point with value greater than $1$. This problem really does need to be solved using gradients.

Comment: is it correct that the max/min occur at local extrema or on the boundary?

Comment: If this is true, I don't think it's necessary to go to the trouble of computing the global maxima on the sphere.

Comment: @FredJefferson, the **global** maximum must be attained by a point which lies in $cl{A}$, you have already shown this result. The **global** minimum must also be attained by a point which lies in $cl(A)$, because the point $(x,y,z)$ where $x=y=0$ and $z=1$ lies in $cl(A)$ and $f(0,0,1)=-1<f(0,\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3})$.

Comment: And yes I think you actually don't need to check the set $cl(A)$ for maxima in detail as I did. We already know that the **global** extrema must lie in $cl(A)$ because they don't lie in $\mathring{A}$. Unfortunately I noticed this after having posted my answer which is unnecesarily lengthy. I will edit my answer

Comment: Thanks. Just for fun, I would like to find the global maxima. I got that the critical points on $cl(A)$ are actually about $(-\frac{1}6, -\frac{1}3, \pm 0.93)$ and $(0,0,1)$, but none of these are global maxima. Did I make a calculation error? I'm basically trying to find the pair(s) $(x,y)$ that maximize(s) $2x^2 + y^3 - 2xy + y^2 - 1.$